# Using regex to find IDENTIFIER in URL and return as a string

Tags: php, regex, string, url, wget

I've got a PHP script that does batch wgets from a database, but need to create a mechanism to generate folders so I can loop it all to save each file in its own folder...

Can one use regex to find the IDENTIFIER (which can be anything/any length, sometimes with underscores, sometimes with hyphens other times not) in following URL or is there some other way? I have no idea about regex...

http://cdn.blah.com/mp4/IDENTIFIER/somefile.mp4

For example, can one find IDENTIFIER and return it as a string? That way I can pass it to write "wget -O /somedir/" . $IDENTIFIER . "/"; and that would help greatly!

Any help very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if this is your site just back up file system back up db, using wget would be inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the identifier using a combination of [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) and [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename):

```
$url = 'http://cdn.blah.com/mp4/IDENTIFIER/somefile.mp4';
$identifier = basename(dirname($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno anything about PHP but I notice that

```
/.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+/.exec(s)
```

pops IDENTIFIER right out for you.

**edit:** a very brief Google suggests the PHP equivalent would be

```
<?php
$subject = "http://cdn.blah.com/mp4/IDENTIFIER/somefile.mp4";
$pattern = "/.*\/([^/]+)\/[^/]+/";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but I dunno how to implement that. It's not PHP?